# How to generically call a method f<T>() on Either<T1,T2> in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

The problem began when one macro was preventing me from being able to use generic method `a<T>(p: T)` so instead I wanted to try the approach of `a(p: Either<T1, T2>)`

Can I somehow get this to work without having to have 2 separate invocations of `b<T>`?

```
pub trait T<Q> {}

struct T1 {}
struct T2 {}
impl T<T1> for T1 {}
impl T<T2> for T2 {}

fn a(p: Either<T1,T2>) {
  b<T>(p.left_or(p.right().unwrap()));
}
```

Comment: Maybe dynamic dispatch i.e. trait objects: `fn a(p: &dyn T)` ?

Comment: Can you specify the desired signature of `b`, because it's not obvious what `b<T>` refers to? Also, the problem is that `T<T1>` and `T<T2>` are separate traits so even with dynamic dispatch, you cannot call `b()` with something that implements `T`. You need a _common_ trait implemented by `T1` and `T2`, and for `b()` to accept a generic argument bound by that trait.

Comment: what is `b` in this code?

Comment: If `b` is a function, the syntax to call it with an explicit type argument is `b::<T>()`.

Comment: Although, `T` is not a type, it's a trait.

Comment: You say you are trying this because you had problems with a different approach, so this looks like an X/Y problem to me. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: "less typing" is usually not a good reason for introducing the runtime overhead of dynamic dispatch. Given the code you have presented, the usual way would be to match the `Either` and call the function for each possibility. For better ergonomics, you might consider implementing your trait for `Either<L, R>`.